# PostgreSQL subquery calculations from unrelated models

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I've been trying different ways of doing this but not sure how to go about it in the best way.

I have several models that are all related to a parent 'Client' model. For this example (which has nothing to do with my actual problem) let's assume Clients have Email Orders and Phone Orders. So each Email Order or Phone Order is related to a client, but have no relationship to each other.

I want to run a query on Clients and return all clients, and the total of a field within the orders for each client (eg: USD Amount - a field that exists in both child models) in addition to perhaps the total TAX for both the orders (so two aggregate columns to be returned).

One way is to run a subquery and another subquery within that for each case - the outer subquery sums the totals from the two inners. But then in this case when I try to capture two fields I get an error saying a Subquery can only return one column.

What's the best way to structure this?

EDIT:

The table structure (massively simplified with email/phone orders having the same structure for the purpose of the example) is as follows:

Client Table -

```
CREATE TABLE clients_client
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  deleted boolean NOT NULL,
  company_name character varying(100)
)
```

Email Orders -

```
CREATE TABLE clients_emailorders
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  added_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  deleted boolean NOT NULL,
  tx_category integer NOT NULL,
  status integer NOT NULL,
  amount numeric(18,8) NOT NULL,
  tax numeric(18,8) NOT NULL,
  tx_id character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  completed_at timestamp with time zone,
  notes text,
  client_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

Phone Orders -

```
CREATE TABLE clients_phoneorders
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  added_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  deleted boolean NOT NULL,
  tx_category integer NOT NULL,
  status integer NOT NULL,
  amount numeric(18,8) NOT NULL,
  tax numeric(18,8) NOT NULL,
  tx_id character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  completed_at timestamp with time zone,
  notes text,
  client_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

The query I want to run (and I have nothing working at the moment so this is illustrative) is something along the following lines:

```
SELECT "clients_client"."id", "clients_client"."company_name", total_order_amount, total_order_tax
FROM "clients_client"
WHERE "clients_client"."deleted" = False
```

Where the 'total_order_amount' is the SUM of all the order amounts for both the child models, and the 'total_order_tax' is the SUM of tax amounts for both the child models.

I should add that each client can have zero or more of each order type.

Comment: `saying a Subquery can only return one column.` That is a *scalar* subquery. In general, a subquery can yield more than one row times more than one column: in fact a table-expression. Just give it an alias and refer to its fields.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question and the query you are using. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I've edited the original question above to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Combine both orders tables using `UNION ALL` operator, and join a result to clients table:

```
SELECT c.company_name,
    sum( o.amount ) as amount,
    sum( o.tax ) as tax
FROM clients_client c
JOIN (
    SELECT client_id ,  amount, tax
    FROM clients_phoneorders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT client_id ,  amount, tax
    FROM clients_emailorders
) o
ON o.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.company_name
```

Comment: Would you recommend this approach even if the two child models were completely different from each other as long as they both had a client_id field and the amount fields I want to operate on (not like the example above)?

Comment: Yes. Structures of tables can be completely different, it doesn't matter. The  one and only restricion is explained in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html `the two queries must be "union compatible", which means that they return the same number of columns and the corresponding columns have compatible data types, as described in Section 10.5.`